# Updating SVN to 1.8 does not work with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I updated to svn 1.8.8

```
svn, version 1.8.8 (r1568071)
   compiled Aug 20 2015, 12:51:30 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

and since then Eclipse won't let me connect to my repository saying

```
Share project was failed.
svn: E155021: This client is too old to work with the working copy at
'/home/sfalk/workspace/lexisnexis/lexisnexis-enrichment-parent' (format '31').
```

I have already removed all project files and tried to [update](http://blog.elijaa.org/2013/09/05/svn-this-client-is-too-old-to-work-with-the-working-copy-format-31/) to Suclipse 1.10

```
http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x
```

but I am getting

> Cannot perform operation. Computing alternate solutions ..

which takes just an eternity and then tells me that it still didn't work.

At the moment it tells me:

```
Your original request has been modified.
  "Subversive SVN Team Provider" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. 
  "Subversive SVN JDT Ignore Extensions (Optional)" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. 
  "Subversive SVN Team Provider Localization (Optional)" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. 
  "Subversive Revision Graph (Optional)" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. 
  "Subversive SVN Integration for the Mylyn Project (Optional)" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. 
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Subversive SVN Team Provider Sources 1.0.0.I20130122-1700 (org.eclipse.team.svn.source.feature.group 1.0.0.I20130122-1700)
  Software currently installed: Subversive SVN Team Provider Sources 2.0.3.I20141224-1700 (org.eclipse.team.svn.sources.feature.group 2.0.3.I20141224-1700)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    The sources of the SVN Team Provider 2.0.3.I20141224-1700 (org.eclipse.team.svn.sources 2.0.3.I20141224-1700)
    The sources of the SVN Team Provider 1.0.0.I20130122-1700 (org.eclipse.team.svn.sources 1.0.0.I20130122-1700)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Subversive SVN Team Provider Sources 1.0.0.I20130122-1700 (org.eclipse.team.svn.source.feature.group 1.0.0.I20130122-1700)
    To: org.eclipse.team.svn.sources.feature.group [1.0.0.I20130122-1700]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Subversive SVN Team Provider Sources 1.0.0.I20130122-1700 (org.eclipse.team.svn.sources.feature.group 1.0.0.I20130122-1700)
    To: org.eclipse.team.svn.sources [1.0.0.I20130122-1700]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Subversive SVN Team Provider Sources 2.0.3.I20141224-1700 (org.eclipse.team.svn.sources.feature.group 2.0.3.I20141224-1700)
    To: org.eclipse.team.svn.sources [2.0.3.I20141224-1700]
```

How can I fix this?